# How to serialize a form with dynamically added inputs using jQuery?

Tags: form-submit, jquery

I've read through a lot of questions addressing similar question but I can't get a grip on it, yet.

I have a simple HTML form just like

```
<form id="edit-items" name="edit-items" onsubmit="saveItems();">
  <input type="submit" value="Save">
  <input class="item" id="ei81" type="hidden" name="i[81]" value="1">
  <input class="item" id="ei124" type="hidden" name="i[124]" value="1">
</form>
```

The two existing hidden inputs could be set upon document loading due to a prior save.
Now I have images (kind of a menu). If they are clicked a corresponding hidden input is appended to the form:

```
<img id="i37" class="clickable-item" src="items/i37.gif" title="item name" onclick="addItem(37,1)" />
```

The addItem function:

```
function addItem(id,n) {
  var zitem = $("#e"+id);
  if ( 0 in zitem ) {
    if ( zitem.val() > 0 ) {
      var newcnt = parseInt(zitem.val()) + n;
      if ( newcnt <= 0 ) {
        zitem.remove();
      }
      else {
        zitem.val(newcnt);
      }
    }
  }
  else if(n == 1) {
    var iform = $("#edit-items");
    iform.append("<input class=\"item\" id=\"e"+id+"\" type=\"hidden\" name=\"i["+id+"]\" value=\"1\">");
  }
}
```

This part all works correct, after clicking the image, my form looks like

```
<form id="edit-items" name="edit-items" onsubmit="saveItems();">
  <input type="submit" value="Save">
  <input class="item" id="ei81" type="hidden" name="i[81]" value="1">
  <input class="item" id="ei124" type="hidden" name="i[124]" value="1">
  <input class="item" id="ei37" type="hidden" name="i[37]" value="1">
</form>
```

which is exactly what I want. But then when hitting the submit button only the first two elements are submitted (the ones which have not been added dynamically).

Now, I read a lot about .bind and .live handlers but I am missing some point obviously. I tried to delete the onclick attribute on the images and to bind the .live to them since they are causing the new inputs:

```
$(".clickable-item").live("click", function() {
  addItem($(this).attr("id"),1);
});
```

However, the ID is not transferred which is needed, though (hence no correct input is added). I learned that .live doesn't bind the handler to any elements but to the event.

Is it even possible to pass the element which has been clicked to the live handler?
Should the images even be watched by .live or should it be bound to something else?

The last thing I learned form another question here is that the inputs should be watched by .live, since they are dynamically added. But what kind of event I would attach? The inputs themselves are not clicked.

I would really appreciate any help as I am cracking my head and starting to get lost on that one.

Thanks in advance,
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding [`live()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/live/): `this` refers to the clicked element, so you can pass it to `addItem` with `addItem(this, 1)`. This part of your code should work.

If you don't add or remove images dynamically then there is no reason to use `live`. You can just use [`click()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/click/) (and yes, don't use `onclick` in the HTML).

---

But I see another problem:

The image id is `i37`. `$(this).attr("id")` will return this value.

In your `addItem` function you then take this value and perform string concatenation. The result will be `$("#ii37")` (note the two `i`s).

The input element you create will have the id `ii37` and not `i37`.

If you correct this to match it with the other elements like in your example (i.e. `i37`) , you will have problems because you have several elements with the same id (the input element and the image). If the image comes before the input field in the hierarchy, then `$("#i37")` will always select the image and you cannot call `.val()` on an image.

As I don't know what is the overall purpose of the code and what you want to do, I cannot give any suggestion how to improve this. Maybe it is enough to just change the prefix of the image and input field ids.

---

> I learned that .live doesn't bind the handler to any elements but to the event.

That is not correct. `.live()` binds the event handler to the document root. Events, if not cancelled, bubble up the DOM tree, so they reach the root eventually. There, the [`event.target` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) property is examined to determine the element that was clicked.

Comment: Thank you for that. I changed the code (also in question text) with the inputs now having ids like "ei37". While this works (inputs are inserted right) .serialize() on the form still returns input values that have not been added.

The overall purpose is to mark different zones. There is a defined set of markers (the images). When a zone form is loaded already existing markers are shown in the form (the preloaded inputs). By clicking any marker the corresponding input is added to the form. Upon clicking the submit button (save) the data shall be stored in the database again.

Comment: *.serialize() on the form still returns input values that have not been added* How can serialize return values that don't exist? I suggest you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo for your problem.

Comment: Sorry, that should have read _.serialize() on the form still returns input values that have not been added **dynamically** only_

Comment: Btw: regarding the doc page (which I have probably read like twenty times today), just _this_ wouldn't work for me, I had to use _$(this)_. Just in case somebody stumbles at that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that fiddle example. That's exactly what I am looking for. I am still using jQuery 1.5.1, but shouldn't be the reason it doesn't work for me, right? Anyways, I'm going to check it once again. Thanks already for your help.

Comment: @Paul: It already worked in 1.4.4 so the version should not be an issue (you can change the jQuery version in the top right). And yes, `this` refers to the *DOM element*, you have to pass it to jQuery to get a jQuery object.

Comment: Ok, making a complete fool of myself: I had a typo in one of the js function (underscore instead of a hyphen). But through your answer I was double-checking on all IDs. I am marking your answer as accepted. This leaves only one last question: Would it have worked without the .live binding? And just for understanding: should .live always be appended to the element(s) which induce the dynamic new elements?

Comment: @Paul: No, you use `live` for dynamic elements you want to bind an event handler to, not to the ones that insert the elements. Example: You insert a lot of buttons `<button>`. To bind an event handler to the existing and all current ones, you would use `$('button').live(...)`. If the elements already exist (like your images), then you don't need to use `live`. So yes, it would work without `live()`.